# Matching a regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to extract the date from the following strings but to no avail.

```js
const strs = [
    `X
       March 17th 2011
`,
    `X
       2011
`,
    `X
    March
       2011
`,
];

console.log(strs.map(s => 
  s.match(/X\s+([a-zA-Z]+?\s*[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?\s*(\d+)/))
);
```

The problem is with the first match, currently it is

```
[
    "X\n       March 17",
    "March",
    "17"
]
```

while it should be

```
[
    "X\n           March 17th 2011",
    "March",
    "17th",
    "2011"
]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Removed that part, sorry.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can the dates change beyond these 3 or is this the entire specification? In other words, are you guaranteed the format `full_month_name day_ending_in_th 4_digit_year` with the first two fields optional? Or is the logic that `X` is some sort of hint point and you want to capture anything up to the next 4 digit year after `X`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
/X(?:\s+([a-zA-Z]+))?(?:\s+([a-zA-Z0-9]+))?\s+(\d+)/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PK9UVE/1/). *Details*:

- `X` - an `X` char
- `(?:\s+([a-zA-Z]+))?` - an optional sequence of one or more whitespaces (`\s+`) and one or more ASCII letters (captured into Group 1)
- `(?:\s+([a-zA-Z0-9]+))?` - an optional sequence of one or more whitespaces (`\s+`) and one or more ASCII letters or digits (captured into Group 2)
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `(\d+)` - Group 3: one or more digits

See a JavaScript demo below:

```js
const strs = ["X\n           March 17th 2011\n", "X\n           2011\n", "X\n        March\n           2011\n"];
const rx = /X(?:\s+([a-zA-Z]+))?(?:\s+([a-zA-Z0-9]+))?\s+(\d+)/;
strs.forEach(s => 
  console.log( s.match(rx) )
);
```

Or, getting full values:

```js
const strs = ["X\n           March 17th 2011\n", "X\n           2011\n", "X\n        March\n           2011\n"];
const rx = /X(?:\s+[a-zA-Z]+)?(?:\s+[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?\s+\d+/g;
strs.forEach(s => 
  console.log( s.match(rx).map(x => x.substr(1).trim().replace(/\s+/g, ' ') ))
);
```

Comment: Just in case: the [solution is confirmed to be working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64128634/matching-a-regex-in-javascript/64133401#comment113401502_64128634). See the demo in the answer, too.